# Sync hub permissions to associated sites via Pnp Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, pnp-powershell, hub-site

I cannot find a setting to sync hubsite permissions to associated sites.  The option isn't enabled when you register a hub site via PowerShell, and I cannot find out how to throw this switch programmatically.  Does anyone know?

[image: Sync Hub Permissions]

[Set-PnpHubSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnphubsite?view=sharepoint-ps) isn't helping as it doesn't have the option as far as I can see...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, we could not enable "**sync hubsite permissions to associated sites**" feature through PowerShell.

We recommend that you use this option which is in Sharepoint Online UI to enable this feature.

For more information, please refer to **[this article](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-sync-hub-permissions-to-the-associated-sites/)**.